# Drag and drop issues in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, tinymce

I'm trying to let users visually move around component placeholders inside a TinyMCE editor, however I can only seem to get drag and drop working with divs in Internet Explorer. Even dragging simple text around seems buggy in Firefox and Chrome.

Any way of getting this done somehow? I've tried finding a plugin or something but no luck so far.

Comment: Are you talking about absolutely positioned elements?

Comment: No, I really only want to move divs relative to the text in the edit box, or maybe in between edit boxes. This works fine in IE, kind of ironic, most of the time it's IE that's causing problems, not the other way around.